# Trying to redirect all subdirectory requests to root but it doesn't work at all

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all /wordpress/ requests to the same address at root.

For example:
/wordpress/foo -> /foo

I tried this answer I found by adding it to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wordpress/.*$ / [R=302]
</IfModule>
```

but needless to say, it just redirects the direct request to /wordpress/ to /.

e.g. a request to /wordpress/foo/ will still be treated as /wordpress/foo/.

I tried everything I found but nothing works.

website address is http://www.ist118.com/

an example address that doesn't redirect correctly is http://www.ist118.com/wordpress/%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84/%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84/

(url is encoded because of utf8 arabic characters)

Complete .htaccess contents:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /wordpress/(.*) /$1 [PT]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule /wordpress/(.*) /$1 [PT]
```

**UPDATED**

I think your .htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /wordpress/(.*) /$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATED**

Just for your information.

If you need just transparent redirection, you should use

```
RewriteRule /wordpress/(.*) /$1 [PT]
```

in this case redirect will transparently and user will still see an old URL in browser's address line

But if you want user to know the URL was changed, you should use

```
RewriteRule /wordpress/(.*) /$1 [R=301]
```

in this case URL will changed in browser's address line too

And one more:

```
R=301 - is for permanently moved URLs (user's browser will rememeber the new URL)
R=302 - is for temporarely moved URLs
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^wordpress/?(.*)" "/$1" [R=302]
```

**UPDATE**: Added question mark after '/' to enable redirect even if there's no subpath.

Comment: it still just redirects the base folder and not when there's a subfolder added to the address. so, basically the same result as before.

Comment: With above, Apache redirects everything beneath /wordpress to /, i.e. /wordpress/blah goes to /blah. Wasn't that the intended behaviour?

Comment: Please note that in .htaccess context the path to match is ALWAYS relative (i.e. doesn't start with /). In the other answer (which I'm unable to comment) the examples starts with a /, and that won't work in .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this I really appreciate it.

Yes, it almost does what I wanted now. 

But while /wordpress/ goes to / and  /wordpress/blah/ goes to /blah, when the structure has an added slash, such as  /wordpress/blah/foo it doesn't change anything at all and it just still goes to /wordpress/blah/foo.

What I mean is it only changes the basic /wordpress/ and up to 1 subfolder. Beyond that it ignores it. is there any way to fix this?